# Map column values in TreeMap as key with line number as values

Tags: java, collections, treemap

I want to read a column of numbers from a file in java. For example:

```
945
922
922
480
480
819
819
289
386
```

and I want to put these numbers in a `TreeMap` as keys. The value for each key will be the number of its line. Therefore, the map will have something like this:

```
{(945:1),(922:2,3),(480:4,5)}
```

I am trying the above, but I get an error.

```
ArrayList<Integer> clusterNums = new ArrayList<>();
String clusterLine;
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer[]>> clusterMap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer[]>>();
while ((clusterLine = clusterFile.readLine()) != null) {
                clusterNums.add(Integer.parseInt(clusterLine));
             }
for (int i = 1; i < clusterNums.size(); i++){
      if (!clusterMap.containsKey(clusterNums.get(i-1))) {
           clusterMap.put(clusterNums.get(i-1), new ArrayList<Integer[]>());
         }
      clusterMap.get(clusterNums.get(i-1)).add(i);
 }
```

Could you please advise me?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The error is saying:

'"no suitable method found for add(int)
    method ArrayList.add(int,Integer[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(Integer[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to Integer"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList<Integer[]>` because `ArrayList` itself is a container to hold your one dimensional `line numbers`, instead use like below:

```
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> clusterMap = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

`ArrayList` will contain the line  numbers of a given number in the file.

suppose current number is : `num`
So check for the presence in the `clusterMap`:

```
if(clusterMap.containsKey(num )){
     clusterMap.get(num).add(lineNumber);
}
else{
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(lineNumber);
    clusterMap.put(num, list);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this what I'm doing checking for clusterNums? Isn't this the same thing?

Comment: Okay, now I see my (silly) mistake... :) Thank you for replying! Seems this is going to be the solution...

Answer (score 1):

The values in the map should be a one dimensional data structure as described in your problem statement. You're using `ArrayList<Integer[]>` which is a list of arrays, a 2D structure.

Comment: Okay, now I see what you meant!

Answer (score 0):

You want to map to multiple values?  This is called a MultiMap!

I recommend this: [Guava TreeMultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html)

basically your value is an arraylist of the values associated with that key.
All you'd have to do is include the guava library and it will be very neat and clean, instead of trying to create your own multimap implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure this is similar to what I want to do. :S

Comment: it is :)
a tree multimap is basically your TreeMap<K,ArrayList<V>>  Which is exactly what everybody else is recommending, except theyre writing the code to represent it too.  Im just saying use the guava library its already been written for you by google

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you. I didn't understand it at first. I would try both choices then! :)